# compact notation for adding scaled identity

Tags: matrices, notation

I want to modify a matrix $A$ by adding some multiple of the identity to it, but I'd like to write this as a multiplication instead of an addition. Let's assume the diagonal components of $A$ are a multiple of the identity (i.e., $A$ would be too if we ignored its off-diagonal components). I would like to scale only these components by a factor of (1+$\eta$) for some $0<\eta<1$, but instead of

$\lambda = A_{11}*\eta \;$ and $\tilde{A} = A + \lambda*I$,

I would much rather write $\tilde{A} = A * (\eta B)$ for some $B$.

The closest thing I have right now is $\tilde{A} = A \circ (\eta I + J)$, where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product and $J$ is a unit matrix (all entries are $1$), but I feel like it'd be nice to write it in terms of a more common matrix product.

Comment: The transform you are after is nonlinear. A form like $\eta B$ can't achieve that.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. Thanks!